# I'm trying to build APK for Rocket BeApp project using this cmd====> flutter build apk --release --no-tree-shake-icons

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview

#Android Studio error for creating an apk from Rocket BeApp project of Flutter

#after running this code>>> flutter build apk --release --no-tree-shake-icons I got the flowing issues,

#See these three pics

1. Android studio pic-1
   [image]
2. Android studio pic-2
   [image]
3. Android studio pic-3
   [image]

## #Admin Portal

admin portal is working fine
[image]

## #I've Tried to check flutter but it looked fine so far.

#flutter and all requirements are up to date & working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have updatd your flutter to 3.7 and it has the problem in it

> Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both

to solve this problem you have to hide it from one place to do this

Search for any file import"material.dart" at plugin "modal_bottom_sheet"

```
import 'material.dart';
```

Replace by:

```
import 'material.dart' hide ModalBottomSheetRoute;
```

Comment: if you problem is solved then accept the answer.